# A question about the divergence of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following is a criteria for divergence:

> $\exists N_0$ such that $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|>1$ for $n\geq N_0$, then $\Sigma{a_n}$ is divergent.

$1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,\dots$ satisfies this criterion. But is it divergent? We don't know whether the sum is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$$

is said to be convergent if the sequence of partial sums

$$b_N = \sum_{n = 1}^N a_n$$

is convergent; that is, if $\{b_N\}_{N = 1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent sequence in the usual sense (in particular, the limit must be a *finite* real / complex number). Since we have

$$b_1 = 1, b_2 = -1, b_3 = 2, b_4 = -2, b_5 = 3, \dots$$

and more generally that

$$b_N = (-1)^{N + 1} \left\lceil \frac N 2 \right\rceil$$

it follows that $\{b_N\}$ is not a convergent series, so the sum is divergent.

Comment: So anything that is not convergent is divergent? I was under the impression that a series is divergent if it sums to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. If the summation is indeterminate, then we call it an indeterminate series (or something of the sort).

Comment: @algebraically_speaking The standard terminology is that "divergent" is the same as "not convergent." To express that the partial sums are tending to $\pm \infty$, one could say "diverging to $\pm \infty$" accordingly.

Comment: I have a few questions if that is true. Here $\alpha=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup a_n$: 1. Shouldn't $\alpha>1$ imply that the series is divergent, as you have an infinite number of terms greater than $1$? 2. Shouldn't $\alpha$ of the series formed by $b_n=\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$, if it is greater than $1$, imply that the series is divergent, as you have an infinite numbers of terms greater than $1$?

Comment: I think both conditions are insufficient to prove that a series is divergent.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking If $\alpha \ne 0$, then the [series is divergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test), so yes to $1$. I don't understand what you're asking in $2$.

Answer (score 0):

$S_{2k+1} = 1 + 3 + ...+ 2k + 1 - 2 - 4 - ... - 2k = k + 1$, and $S_{2k} = 1 + 3 +...+ 2k - 1 - 2 - 4 -..- 2k = -k$. Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} S_{2k+1} = +\infty$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} S_{2k} = -\infty$. This shows the sequence of partial sum $\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ diverges, hence the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n$ diverges.